# Python sleep when making 10 requests

Tags: python, sleep

I'm using

```
requests.get()
```

to call the same server again and again, but I am limited to 30 requests per minute. How can I make the program sleep for a minute when I make 30 requests. The challenge is

```
requests.get()
```

are spread everywhere in my code, I can't put them in a loop.

Comment: `time.sleep(60)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to wrap the requests. Something like this:

```
class RequestLimiter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.count == 30:
            time.sleep(60)
            self.count = 0
            return requests.get(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.count += 1
            requests.get(*args, **kwargs)

def main():
    # If this is through your whole program, 
    # you might want to make this global- be careful with that!
    r = RequestLimiter()
    r.get(url, args)
```

Depending on your requirements are, you might want to change some of this. For example, as it's coded, your count will increase regardless of whether your `get` succeeds or fails. That may or may not be what you want. If you do decide to make a global instance of this class, then you have to worry about concurrent access to the `count` variable (if you're using concurrency).

Comment: While your code does limit the number of requests to 30 before sleeping, that's not the same as allow only up to 30 _per minute_. I believe it needs some sense of the interval between requests made to really do what the OP needs.

Comment: @martineau, OP's original question did ask how to sleep for a minute after each 30 requests. I posted this code as the simplest way to do that. I do agree, though, that it's not the most time-efficient way to limit the requests. I'll try to post another answer tonight using your interval method if I have time.

Comment: I didn't mean your could wasn't efficient, just that it needs to calculate the number of requests per minute to really do what the OP wants done. In addition, it may also need to check to see whether the same request is being made or not and adjust or reset accordingly.